# Sample from a 0:Vector[i]

Tags: r, montecarlo

In R:

I have a vector **

```
y = sample(0:200, 1e4, replace = TRUE)
```

I want to create a variable ‘x’ such that:

```
x = sample(0:y[i], 1e4, replace = TRUE)
```

Where y[i] are the values of y1, y2, …, y1e4 created from the sample function before. For example if y1 = 50 then I would like the first entry of x = sample(0:50) etc. However I am not sure how to do this. I have tried for loops but have gotten no where.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: So, you don't need `1e4` results, just the first so `y =sample(0:200, 1e4, replace = TRUE)[1]` and then x = sample(0:y...?

Comment: @Chris I was confused at first too. I think OP wants `x` to be the same length as `y`, and `x[i]` is sampled from `0:y[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
x <- as.integer(runif(1e4)*sample(201, 1e4, TRUE))
```

Benchmarking:

```
f1 <- function() sapply(sample(0:200, 1e4, replace = TRUE), function(i) sample(0:i, size = 1))
f2 <- function() as.integer(runif(1e4)*sample(201, 1e4, TRUE))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f1 = f1(),
                               f2 = f2())
#> Unit: microseconds
#>  expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
#>    f1 38877.3 47070.50 49294.770 48625.00 50175.35 97045.0   100
#>    f2   508.2   522.05   555.602   531.45   549.45  2080.8   100
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
y = sample(0:200, 1e4, replace = TRUE)
x = sapply(y, \(i) sample(0:i, size = 1))
```

Or the equivalent using a `for` loop:

```
x = numeric(length(y))
for(i in seq_along(y)) {
  x[i] = sample(0:y[i], size = 1)
}
```

If efficiency matters, this might be a bit faster on very long input:

```
x = floor(runif(length(y), min = 0, max = y + 1))
```